# Change multiple div contents based on same classname?

Tags: jquery

I have unique id's for these but I want to change all div's with class="on" to contents "Goodbye". Is there a way to do this without having to call to each id individually?

**This...**

```
<div class="on" id="1">Hi</div>
<div class="random" id="2">Hi</div>
<div class="on" id="3">Hi</div>
```

**...would look like this.**

```
<div class="on" id="1">Goodbye</div>
<div class="random" id="2">Hi</div>
<div class="on" id="3">Goodbye</div>
```

Comment: In the HTML spec IDs must be unique and not be numeric. For multiple elements to share an identifier, use a class name instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('.on').html('Goodbye');
```

Or [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('.on').text('Goodbye');
```

Comment: This will change ALL classnames that equal on?

Answer (score 0):

How are you planning on changes the contents? Click events with jQuery? If it's click events you would do something like so:

```
<div class="content">Hi</div>
<div class="content">Hi</div>
<div class="content">Hi</div>
```

Then you can say:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content').click(function(){
     $(this).html('Goodbye');
  });
});
```

I didn't test this but it's where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you can do something similar with jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="on" id="1">Byte</div>
    <div class="random" id="2">Bye</div>
    <div class="on" id="3">Byte</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#container").children().each(function(n, i) {
        $(div.on).replaceWith( "<div class="on" id="this.id">" Goodbye + "</div>" );
    });
</script>
```